# Xamarin.Android: Getting "Error inflating class fragment" exception while showing DialogFragment after another DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I am trying to show 2 DialogFragments one after another with different contents. When I show them seperately for testing, both work fine perfactly, but when I try to show them one after another, the I got the following exception.

> {Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment ---> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment}

Exception occure on the following line of code

```
View view = Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_fragment_goods_delivery, null);
```

The above code line is declared in "OnCreateDialog" method. I could not get any information from this exception statement nor from any forum or resource to resolve it. So seeking some help from experts in this regard please. Many Thanks

Update:
I am using one simple fragment in dialog as well. When I remove the fragment code then it works fine but when I insert fragment code, it cause above mentioned exception. Let me inform you that fragment code is very simple. When I used dialog seperately, I mean without showing another dialog in its callback function then it works fine even with fragment. But when I show another dialog in first's callback function then it cause exception.

Comment: errorscreenshot can  be  seen here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HePX7RWT7VupbR110r2bRX9NviTWwjUF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you show the codes  ?

Comment: I am sorry @LeoZhu-MSFT, there is a lot of code, I can not share the whole code.

Comment: Could you show the codes of the fragment ?